# Basic Regular expression for matching all lines except given set of lines

Tags: regex

Can someone explain using basic regular expression (not lookahead like extensions please) to match all content except matching set of lines

For  example if I  want to match everything in content except first three lines, I can think of doing this in two steps:

1. `(.*\n){3}` matches first three lines
2. Match everything except lines matched in last step

I tried expression like:

`[^(.*\n){3}].*\n`

[image]

But this isn't  working.
How to do the second step ?

Comment: Just capture them, `^(?:.*\n){3}([\s\S]*)`, the result will be in Group 1.

Comment: Also using `[^(.*\n){3}]` means none of the listed chars in the character class as noted in the image.

Comment: You mention BRE, are you using some *nix tool for this? You should mention where you are using the regex. And how, if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic to me:

```js
^(?:.*\n){3}\K[\w\W]*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/f4wZsQ/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (3 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){3}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       'K'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\w\W]*                  any character of: word characters (a-z, A-
                           Z, 0-9, _), non-word characters (all but a-
                           z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
```